# Is it possible to take the driving license test in English in Belgium?

Tags: driving-license, belgium, language

I am a Pakistani living in Belgium. I am planning to apply for a driving licence but I can't speak Dutch or French. I can speak English; can I take the driving license test in English in Belgium?

Comment: Do you mean ‘can I take a driving licence TEST in English in Belgium’?

Comment: @glorfindel This is really over the line, you should reconsider participating in this site if you can’t avoid insulting people.

Answer (score 3):

Like most European countries, obtaining a driving license in Belgium consists of a theoretical and a practical part. You'll probably need (quite) some lessons for both parts before taking the examination.

According to [the government website](https://www.vlaanderen.be/rijbewijs-b-voor-auto/theorie-examen-voor-rijbewijs-b), it's possible to do the theoretical examination with the help of an English speaking interpreter provided by the examination center:

> Examination with a interpreter
>
> It's possible to do the theoretical examination with the help of a sworn French, German or English or sign language interpreter.
>
> You pay the base amount of 15 euro + an extra 51 euro for the translator's help. The examination center picks the sworn interpreter.

Original text:

> Examen met een tolk
>
> Het theorie-examen is mogelijk met bijstand van een Franse, Duitse of Engelse beëdigde tolk of van een beëdigde doventolk.
>
> U betaalt het basistarief van 15 euro + 51 euro extra voor de bijstand van de tolk. Het examencentrum kiest de beëdigde tolk.

However, for the [practical examination](https://www.vlaanderen.be/rijbewijs-b-voor-auto/praktijkexamen-rijbewijs-b) you'll need to bring your own:

> Assistance of an interpreter
>
> You can take the practical examination with help of a sworn French, German or English interpreter. To be sure, contact the examination center in advance.
>
> You choose and pay your own sworn French, German or English interpreter. The interpreter must provide evidence to the examination center that he is a sworn interpreter.

Original text:

> Bijstand door een tolk
>
> U kunt het praktijkexamen afleggen met bijstand van een Franse, Duitse of Engelse beëdigde tolk. Neem daarvoor zeker op voorhand contact op met het examencentrum.
>
> De Franse, Duitse of Engelse beëdigde tolk kiest en betaalt u zelf. De tolk moet aan het examencentrum een bewijs voorleggen om aan te tonen dat hij een beëdigde tolk is.

This is the situation in Flanders (the Dutch-speaking part of Belgium); I'd be surprised if it was much different than Wallonia (the French-speaking part).